# Debug/fix a key autorepeat issue?

Tags: keyboard-event

I'm using Caps Lock as a Control key, configured with the following command (I'm running Gnome):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options \
  "['caps:ctrl_modifier']"
```

Sometimes when I press a Control-modified key, the key autorepeats. For example, I'll type Ctrl-w and all of a sudden the w key starts repeating as if I were holding it down. I suspect a keyup event is being lost. The repeat goes on indefinitely until I hit another key.

Also maybe related, sometimes when I press a Control-modified key, it simply does nothing, as if I "pressed it wrong". I just try again and it works, but I suspect this is another symptom of the same underlying problem.

How can I debug/fix this? I'd like to see which keyboard events are being sent, and when.

---

**Update**

I still haven't found a fix for this (not sure what to do about the answer below, because it's helpful information, but did not solve my issue), but [I used xinput](https://github.com/ivanbrennan/kbdebug) to monitor the keyboard events involved.

It appears to be related to "rollover", because I can only reproduce the key-repeat bug with key-sequences like `press Caps`, `press W`, `release Caps`, `release W` (as opposed to releasing W before releasing Caps).

I also can only reproduce the bug in X, not in a virtual console.

I emptied out the `xkb-options` I had set via `gsettings`, and am now relying on `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-keyboard.conf` instead:

```
Section "InputClass"
  Identifier "Keyboard catchall"
  MatchIsKeyboard "on"
  Option "XkbModel" "pc104"
  Option "XkbLayout" "us"
  Option "XkbOptions" "ctrl:nocaps"
  Option "XkbVariant" ""
EndSection
```

I switched `caps:ctrl_modifier` to `ctrl:nocaps` because it works in the virtual console as well as X.

So I'm still hunting for a solution, but I feel I've at least learned a few things in the process.

Comment: It might be easier to make caps a control key in X rather than gnome. Especially if gnome is giving you some strange behavior.

Comment: @datUser how might I do that?

Comment: try using the XKB option `ctrl:nocaps` instead of `caps:ctrl_modifier`.  they are subtly different options.  compare the definitions in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ctrl` and `../symbols/capslock` for details.

Comment: @quixotic Thanks for the suggestion. While digging into this, I actually ended up switching to `ctrl:nocaps` because that works in virtual console as well. It didn't solve my problem, but it was a good find, and got me thinking more clearly about keysyms.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the control key behavior in XServer rather than Gnome (assuming you aren't using wayland instead of X):

## Using `setkbmap`

1. Get your keyboard layout:

   ```
   setxkbmap -query
   ```

   Look for the stanza labeled `layout`. Something like `gb` for an English layout. Yours may be different.
2. Modify the keyboard layout's options using the same layout your are alreay using in #2 above:

   ```
   setxkbmap -layout gb -option ctrl:nocaps
   ```

   Here the `ctrl:nocaps` option makes your caps lock an additional control key. To make this change permanent you can add it to your `.xinitrc` file if you are starting X with `startx` or `xinit` from a terminal. If you aren't doing that [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247706/start-script-when-gnome-starts-up) for how to run a command at login for Gnome.

## Using `xmodmap`

Create the following `.Xmodmap` file in your home dir:

```
!
! Make Caps_Lock another Control_L
!
remove Lock = Caps_Lock
keysym Caps_Lock = Control_L
add Lock = Caps_Lock
```

You can then run the following at start up to make this change active for your X session:

```
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

Once you have something you like you can either add this command to your `.xinitrc` or use the same method as linked above to make this permanent.

## Going Deeper

You can also change caps to control at the kernel level using `loadkeys`.

The basics here are to use `dumpkeys` to dump your existing key map to a file. Change the mapping for caps lock and then use `loadkeys` to load your new keymap.

Note that since you are making changes to how the kernel reads the keyboard input, these changes will need root privileges. Here's a [github gist](https://gist.github.com/KalenAnson/ce0ff763ad8961132959) with the relevant modifications and some instructions.