# How to debug keyboard on Linux

Tags: linux, drivers, keyboard, hardware, debugging

I want to debug my keyboard and figure out what would happen after I press a key.

Is there any debug tools or solutions to track the keyboard events or handlers?

I searched the Internet and only found one useful answer ([Debug/fix a key autorepeat issue?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/424607/debug-fix-a-key-autorepeat-issue))

For example, I press a Volume control key, how does it trigger an event and control the driver to turn up/down?

And how do I track the control flow of it?

I'm using arch Linux on my laptop, so any solution for Linux is welcome.

Comment: Look no further as this question has already been answered: https://superuser.com/questions/248517/show-keys-pressed-in-linux

Comment: See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/403692/193028) for driver level. layers. Once you have an X event, applications grab the keyboard. See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59141/find-x-org-pointer-grab-owner/62252#62252) how to debug this. The first candidate for Volume control keys etc. is your window manager (also as part of the Desktop environment).

Comment: Promising solutions ! Thank you for your answers @dirkt and Artem S. Tashkinov.

Answer (score 1):

You can observe raw USB events from the keyboard input device. Assuming you can find your keyboard here: `ls /dev/input/by-id/*kbd`, you can read events directly from that file.

An example where [fmbtuinput.py](https://github.com/intel/fMBT/blob/devel/utils/fmbtuinput.py) prints human readable events:

`sudo python fmbtuinput.py -p /dev/input/by-id/*kbd`

This works for other USB input devices, too.